# There are no error when i debugging it but it came out with only login failed when i login it with the correct id

Tags: c#

It only came out with login failed but it can be run. I have linked it with Mysql database.

My code:

```
MysqlConn.Open();
string UserName = textUserName.Text;
string Password = textPassword.Text;
MySqlCommand MysqlCmd = new MySqlCommand();
MysqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT  Username,Password FROM user.register WHERE Username='" + textUserName.Text + "' AND Password='" + textPassword.Text + "'";
MysqlCmd.Connection = MysqlConn;
MySqlDataReader myReader = null;
```

or anything wrong in here?

```
                string strPasswrd;
                string strUserName;

                strUserName = (myReader["Username"].ToString());

                strPasswrd = (myReader["Passwrd"].ToString());


                if (UserName == strUserName && Password == strPasswrd)
```

Comment: Try the username `' OR 1 = 1; -- `. P.S. I recommend debugging your code (i.e. stepping through from line to line).

Comment: ok John thanks a lot

Comment: i have try debugging it but 0 error came out

Comment: Have you checked your username and password - if there are no spaces bevor an after?

Comment: @Lau debugging is more than running a project in debug mode. You should also inspect the variables as you step through the code. For example, what are the values just before your `if` statement?

Comment: Obligatory [little bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) alert - use parameters instead of concatenating values inside query string. The concatenated query string is prone to syntax errors. Also check if both parameters has proper value.

Comment: thanks a lot sir i have found out my mistake the values are declare wrongly